Capturing VLAN tagging information with Ansible
I'm new to Ansible and I need help with a code I'm writing. I need to capture the output of this Dell switch command:
show interfaces switchport | find Name: | except 802.1QTagged: | except Vlan
Which generates this:
Name: GigabitEthernet 1/1
U       1641
T       1007,1076




Name: GigabitEthernet 1/2
U       1641
T       1007,1076




Name: GigabitEthernet 1/3
U       1641
T       1007,1076

And put these contents into a dictionary where the key is the interface name with values untagged for the content of U and tagged for the contents of T
This is the playbook I'm running:
---
     - hosts: [dellos9]
      connection: network_cli
      gather_facts: no

      tasks:
      - name: Include secrets and vars
        include_vars: dell_vars.yml

      - name: "Get Dell EMC OS9 VLAN info"
        dellos9_command:
          commands:
            - 'show interfaces switchport | find Name: | except 802.1QTagged: | except Vlan'
        register: switchport_output

      - name: Parsing Command_9 output
        set_fact:
          output_items: "{{  switchport_output.stdout_lines[0] | map('regex_findall','[\\S]+') | list | select() }}"
        when:  switchport_output.stdout_lines is defined

      - name: Process output_items and set variables
        set_fact:
          my_int: "{{ item.1 + ' ' + item.2 if item.0 == 'Name:' }}"
          my_untagged: "{{ item.1 if item.0 == 'U' }}"
          my_tagged: "{{ item.1 if item.0 == 'T' }}"
        loop: "{{ output_items }}"

      - name: Display interface details
        debug:
          msg: "Interface: {{ my_int }} Untagged: {{ my_untagged }} Tagged: {{ my_tagged }}"

I hope someone more experienced can help me. TIA
And this is the output I'm getting from running the playbook:
ok: [switch] => (item=['Name:', 'GigabitEthernet', '1/1'])
ok: [switch] => (item=['U', '1641'])
ok: [switch] => (item=['T', '1007,1076'])
ok: [switch] => (item=['Name:', 'GigabitEthernet', '1/2'])
ok: [switch] => (item=['U', '1641'])
ok: [switch] => (item=['T', '1007,1076'])
ok: [switch] => (item=['Name:', 'GigabitEthernet', '1/3'])
ok: [switch] => (item=['U', '1641'])
ok: [switch] => (item=['T', '1007,1076'])
TASK [Display interface details] **********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [switch] => {
    "msg": "Interface:  Untagged:  Tagged: 1007,1076"
}


Just curious because I have Dell servers but not Dell network devices, does the dellos9_facts module not provide the vlan information? If it does I would bet that would be easier to parse.

The structure of the input data makes this a relatively thorny problem to solve with just Ansible (update: I lied; see below). Your life will be much easier if you move the parsing logic into a Python filter. If we place the following in filter_plugins/filter.py:
def parse_interfaces(v):
    interfaces = {}
    for line in v:
        if line.startswith("Name"):
            name = line.split(": ")[1]
            interfaces[name] = {}
        elif line.startswith("U"):
            interfaces[name]["untagged"] = line.split()[1].split(",")
        elif line.startswith("T"):
            interfaces[name]["tagged"] = line.split()[1].split(",")

    return interfaces


class FilterModule:
    def filters(self):
        return {"parse_interfaces": parse_interfaces}

Then we can write a playbook like this:
    - set_fact:
        switch_interfaces: "{{ switchport_output.stdout_lines[0] | parse_interfaces }}"

    - debug:
        var: switch_interfaces

And get this output:
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "switch_interfaces": {
        "GigabitEthernet 1/1": {
            "tagged": [
                "1007",
                "1076"
            ],
            "untagged": [
                "1641"
            ]
        },
        "GigabitEthernet 1/2": {
            "tagged": [
                "1007",
                "1076"
            ],
            "untagged": [
                "1641"
            ]
        },
        "GigabitEthernet 1/3": {
            "tagged": [
                "1007",
                "1076"
            ],
            "untagged": [
                "1641"
            ]
        }
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   



After thinking about it for a bit, I realized that we can actually adapt your current solution and solve it like this:
    - name: Parsing Command_9 output
      set_fact:
        output_items: "{{ switchport_output.stdout_lines[0] | select }}"
      when:  switchport_output.stdout_lines is defined

    - with_sequence: start=0 end={{output_items|length-1}} stride=3
      vars:
        interfaces: {}
        name: "{{ output_items[item|int].split(': ')[1] }}"
        untagged: "{{ output_items[item|int+1].split()[1] }}"
        tagged: "{{ output_items[item|int+2].split()[1] }}"
      set_fact:
        interfaces: >-
          {{
          interfaces|combine({name: {"tagged": tagged, "untagged": untagged}})
          }}

    - debug:
        var: interfaces

This produces as output:
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "interfaces": {
        "GigabitEthernet 1/1": {
            "tagged": "1007,1076",
            "untagged": "1641"
        },
        "GigabitEthernet 1/2": {
            "tagged": "1007,1076",
            "untagged": "1641"
        },
        "GigabitEthernet 1/3": {
            "tagged": "1007,1076",
            "untagged": "1641"
        }
    }
}

(To be clear I still prefer the Python solution; I think it's easier to read and generally more maintainable.)

Great! I'll try this soon and come back to you with the results. TYVM!

Hi, I tried your ansible approach and I got this error:
fatal: [switch]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: {{ output_items[item|int].split(': ')[1] }}: 'list object' has no attribute 'split'...
I ran the command on the switch to confirm the output and this is what I got:
switch#show interfaces switchport | find Name: | except 802.1QTagged: | except Vlan
Name: GigabitEthernet 1/1
U       1641
T       1007
Name: GigabitEthernet 1/2
U       1641
T       1007
Name: GigabitEthernet 1/3
U       1641
T       1007

But when I write the contents of output_items into a text file:
[['show', 'interfaces', 'switchport', '|', 'find', 'Name:', '|', 'except', '802.1QTagged:', '|\x1b[64D', '\x1b[67D$erfaces', 'switchport', '|', 'find', 'Name:', '|', 'except', '802.1QTagged:', '|', 'except', '\x1b[65D', '\x1b[67D$switchport', '|', 'find', 'Name:', '|', 'except', '802.1QTagged:', '|', 'except', 'Vlan'], ['Name:', 'GigabitEthernet', '1/1'], ['U', '1641'], ['T', '1007'], ['Name:', 'GigabitEthernet', '1/2'], ['U', '1641'], ['T', '1007'], ['Name:', 'GigabitEthernet', '1/3'], ['U', '1641'], ['T', '1007']]

I guess those extra lines are messing with the code @larsks game me. Any idea of how to get rid of them? Thank you

It's possible the content of switchport_output is different than I have assumed based on your description; you never actually show the content of that variable in your question. Here is a link to a complete, runnable test that includes both the playbook and the test output. This runs and produces the output I've described.
